# Can I play against any other CPUs past PRO status?

Tags: wii-sports

I've been playing Wii Tennis, and while its a fun experience, it's rather boring seeing the same CPU over and over.

This occurs when I'm at the【PR✪】level, or 1000 skill points. Anyways, after that I just see the same CPU again. It's Elisa and this other girl I can't really remember.

Are there any other CPU besides them that I can play against? I'd rather do this without using a new Mii.

Answer (score 0):

Elisa and Sarah are the champion Miis of Tennis. You'll need to beat them in order to face off against harder (and different) Miis.